# JavaCC not going to next possible token

Tags: java, javacc

I have this two tokens < import> and <\import>, and I need to capture all data inside this TAG. I've tried this code:

```
< CODIGO_JAVA_IMPORT_OPEN: "<import>" >
< CODIGO_JAVA_IMPORT_CLOSE: "<\\import>" >

void InsertImportJavaCode():{}
{
    < CODIGO_JAVA_IMPORT_OPEN >
    InsertImportJavaCodeRecursiva() 
}

void InsertImportJavaCodeRecursiva():
{
    Token t;
}
{
    (
        LOOKAHEAD(2)
        t = < CODIGO_JAVA_IMPORT_CLOSE >
    |
        t = < ~[] > 
        {
            // code to use information of token t
        }
        InsertImportJavaCodeRecursiva()
    )
}
```

But, JavaCC always goes in the first option of InsertImportJavaCodeRecursiva()
Ex.: if I have a import code like this:

```
<import>
    import something from there.
<\import>
```

JavaCC throw a error that the token "import something from there." is not <\import>.

Comment: There's something you aren't telling us.  Why is `import something from there.` a token?  Please show all the token definitions.

Comment: There is no reason for the `LOOKAHEAD(2)`. Delete it.

Comment: Also.  Have you turned on the debug options? If JavaCC doesn't behave the way you think it should, it's usually quick to turn on the debug options and read the output than to ask a question on stackexchange.

Comment: About LOOKAHEAD(2) I agree.

Comment: Now, "import something from there" is inside of import TAG just as an example. 
I need that this code capture anything inside the TAG

Comment: I've tried DEBUG_PARSER and DEBUG_TOKEN_MANAGER, but couldn't undestand why that error occurs.
For me, it should recognize anything until <\import> is not find,

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact text of the input and the exact text of the output with DEBUG_TOKEN_MANAGER turned on?  Also include the whole .jj file.

Comment: Thanks Theodore, now I undestood how JavaCC works. I found a different way to do what I desire.